# Border on part of ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting

I need to outline with border the group of cells in ArrayPlot. More precisely in my case I would like to outline all blocks of two black squares in the following line.

```
ArrayPlot[{{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, Mesh -> True]
```

Comment: Would a block of four black squares be outlined as two blocks of two black squares, as in Istvan's answer below?  Or would a block of contiguous black squares be outline if its length is exactly two?  Or at least two?  Or do any two adjacent black squares get outlined (which I assume makes all squares get outlined if there are three or more consecutive black squares)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with `Mesh`, as this would require non-continuous mesh lines along the horizontal dimension, which (according to my knowledge) is not possible in `ArrayPlot`. But you can easily create your own array plot. First, I replace each pair of black blocks with placeholders (with `{2, 3}`) to obtain their positions (where a `2` is), and then create black rectangles over a row of white ones in `Graphics`:

```
d = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};

pos = Flatten@Position[(d //. {x___, PatternSequence[1, 1], y___} :> {x, 2, 3, y}), 2];

Graphics[{
  MapIndexed[{EdgeForm@Black, FaceForm@GrayLevel[1 - #],
              Rectangle[{First@#2, 0}, {First@#2 + 1, 1}]} &, d],
  {EdgeForm@{Red, Thick}, Rectangle[{#, 0}, {# + 2, 1}]} & /@ pos
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This works for any list, even ones with excess black blocks (note that it starts blocks from the left):

```
d = {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way, using `ArrayPlot` along with `Epilog`:

```
g[data_] :=  Module[{f}, f[{_} | {}, r_] := r; 
   f[{a_, b_, c___}, s_] := If[b == a + 1, f[{c}, Append[s, a]], f[{b, c}, s]];
   ArrayPlot[data, Mesh -> True, Epilog -> {Orange, Thickness[.01], 
   Line[{{#, 0}, {# + 2, 0}, {# + 2, 1}, {#, 1}, {#, 0}}] & /@ 
   f[(Position[data, 1][[All, 2]] - 1), {}]}]]
```

**Examples**

```
g[{{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}]
g[{{1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}]
```

[image: arrays]

Answer (score 0):

```
Style[Grid[{{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, 
   Frame -> True] /. {x_?OddQ -> 
    Item[x, Background -> Green, ItemSize -> 2, Frame -> True, 
     FrameStyle -> {Thick, Directive[Red, 12]}]}]
```

> [image]

Corrected Version: Initially I didn't pay attention on it being blocks of two, which I have corrected now,

```
Block[{t, t1, 
  t2}, {t = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1} //. {a___, c_ 1, c_ 1, b___} -> {a, {c, 2}, b}; 
  t1 = t /. {{a_, b_}, c_} -> Apply[Sequence, {{a, b}, {a, c}}], 
  t2 = t1 /. {a_, b_} -> ConstantArray[1, 2]}; 
 Grid[{t2}, 
   Frame -> True] /. {x_?eq -> 
    Item[x, Background -> Green, Frame -> True, 
     FrameStyle -> {Thick, Directive[Red, 12]}]}]
eq[x_] := Equal[x, {1, 1}]
```

> [image]

In case of `{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}`

> [image]

Comment: Does not work properly with `{{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}`

Comment: @DavidCarraher:I am getting correct output,what error are you getting ?

Comment: The "bits" with `1` should not be wrapped individually, but rather by pairs.  Also, for the data I provided, there should be no border around the `1` at positions 2 and 6.   See my second example or István's first.